# How does Google determine the type of a place?

Tags: web-services, google-places-api, google-places

I'm a sociologist and I'm trying to use Google Places data in my research project. I need to know how Google determines the type(s) of a given place. Is it done through algorithms, or manual classification, or user report, etc.? This information is crucial to my research methodology, but I haven't been able to find the answer in the Google Places API documentation or on Stack Overflow. I'd really appreciate it if anyone can answer my question or point me in the right direction.